# nginx Times Out Uploading Files - Way Under Timeout Limit

Tags: proxy, nginx, upload

I have an application that can accept file uploads and puts those onto S3.  Some files have been failing to upload when going through the `nginx` reverse-proxy.

Now, I have `keepalive_timeout 120;` set in the nginx.conf as well as

```
client_max_body_size 100m;  <--- server {}

proxy_connect_timeout 300;  <--  location / {}
proxy_send_timeout 300;     <--  location / {}
proxy_read_timeout 300;     <--  location / {}
send_timeout 300;           <--  location / {}
```

set on my application's sites-available/ sites-enabled configurations.

Even after restarting `nginx` this issue reoccurs.  Relevant error.log message:

```
2014/06/12 13:06:52 [error] 2782#0: *1562089 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 173.22.158.100, server: *.url.me, request: "POST /policy/5399ea3712500dc3447ec14d/fileUpload HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/policy/5399ea3712500dc3447ec14d/fileUpload", host: "url.me", referrer: "http://url.me/policy/5399ea3712500dc3447ec14d"
```

The thing is, I don't think this is actually a timeout issue.  Uploading a file takes around 8 seconds total to upload without going through the proxy.  Using the proxy will have the file hang for a minute or two and then errors out.

90% of files uploaded into the application are PDF's, all of them underneath the body size limit.

So, what would you suggest?